# Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE using BeatifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to parse a webpage made with PHP using BeautifulSoup. My problem is my script show this error:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE</p>
<p>Filename: hooks/detecta_idioma.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 110</p>
</div>
```

when I try to do this

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
web = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print web
etiquetas = web('a')
```

I thought that this error for executing my script by command line instead of using a web browser but, executing this script from Apache, I have the same error.

Anyone know how can I define that for parsing the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the page requires you to have the `Accept-Language` header passed along with your request. Here is an example how to do that with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

url = "my url"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept-Language": "en-US,en"})
html = response.content
web = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```